# How to define various vars at global level

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is more an academic question than anything else. I can define three variables at the global level by doing:

```
first = "something"
second = "other"
third = "new"
```

However, I have about 50 variables that I have to add, and so I was wondering I could have have either a `map` or `tuple` and then update the global environment somehow. For example, something like this:

```
toupdate = [('first', 'something'), ('second', 'other'), ('third', 'new')]
globals().update({i[0]: i[1] for i in toupdate})
```

The issue with the above is that it adds the global `'first'` and not `first`. How could this be done?

(Hmm... actually now when I try the above it seems to work. But not sure if that's the proper way to do it.)

Comment: I don't understand.  `'if'` isn't one of the strings you listed.

Comment: @DanielWalker I just meant stringified, but I think I may be wrong there.

Comment: There's nothing proper about having 50 global variables.  Rethink your design.

Comment: @JohnZwinck they're math constants and such. Not too far off from: `>>> import math;len(vars(math))` `64`.

Comment: Then why not keep it simple and just write them as in your first example?  That's how all existing libraries do it.

Comment: If these variables need to be defined from the environment, or otherwise can't/shouldn't be defined in code, they should be coming from `os.environ` or from a configuration file, and there's rarely a good case for any variable being global (not least of all because variables in Python are mutable).

Comment: You need to write the name-value combination somewhere explicitly anyway, it’s not like you could omit or abbreviate that in any way. The first way is already the simplest, most readable, most maintainable way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
data = [('first', 'something'), ('second', 'other'), ('third', 'new')]
for i in data:
    globals()[i[0]] = i[1]

print(first, second, third)
```

Output:

```
something other new
```

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit." That's just a Python mantra, but it holds pretty often, and in this case it's a good one: Globals are almost always a sign of a design issue, and defining globals on the fly is a very bad idea.

Comment: @kungphu I know it already, but the question was how to define global variables using `globals()` and I think I answered the question and this solves the problem that is asked

Comment: OK, but telling someone how to do something that really isn't a good idea is kind of counterproductive in terms of the asker's development and their coworkers' sanity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to make 50 variables in a global scope, they probably are constants, and that's probably the case when you could use [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api)

```py
import enum

toupdate = [('first', 'something'), ('second', 'other'), ('third', 'new')]

SomeEnum = enum.Enum('SomeEnum', toupdate)
```

And if you *really* need to have it flat in `globals`, of course, there is a way

```py
vars().update(SomeEnum.__members__)
```